summer holiday or summer vacation
When school ends in summer what starts then: summer holiday (BrE) or summer vacation (US English) or both can be used interchangeably in Britain and the US, or the term summer holiday is "strictly" used only in Britain and summer vacation in the US.

Monica Cellio addresses this at the duplicate.

I (BrE) would say that the summer holidays start - during them, the family might go on holiday to the seaside. British universities tend to use vacation for the breaks between terms.
